# Flowplayer adding steps to video

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, flowplayer

Hey guys how can I add steps to a video with some HTML like:

Step 1 -> 00:00 | Step 2 -> 03:01 | Step 3 -> 05:33.

Is there something that [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) offers for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it through [Flowplayer's JavaScript API](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/player.html). Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/haochi/rvdWA/1/).

Basically, you just call the `seek` method on the player.

```
$f("player").seek(55 /* seconds */);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. For some reason I can only award you in 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this really simple example to play with. It works in chrome and firefox. I am just using plain html 5 and javascript and a button (which is rendered pretty small btw) and I used alot of info from [here](http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2010/03/03/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio-2). Hope this helps.

```
        function changeTheChapter()
        {

            var currentChapter = parseFloat(document.getElementById("currentChapter").value);
            var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("tehplayer");

            var positon = [];

            positon[0] = 0;
            positon[1] = 30;
            positon[2] = 60;

            videoPlayer.currentTime = positon[currentChapter];
            document.getElementById("currentChapter").value = parseFloat(currentChapter+1);
            //videoPlayer.currentTime = position[currentChapter];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Video For Everybody Generator
    MP4 Video Ogg Video WebM Video Poster Image Fallback Title Width Height Autoplay XML Formatting Embed as HTML5+Flash HTML5 Flash Poster Flash Player
    Preview
    Big Buck Bunny

    Download video: MP4 format | Ogg format | WebM format
    Source Code

    <!-- "Video For Everybody" v0.4.2 by Kroc Camen of Camen Design -->
    <video id="tehplayer" controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </video>
    <input type="hidden" id="currentChapter" value="0" />
    <p>
        <strong>Download video:</strong> 
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">MP4 format</a> | <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv">Ogg format</a> | 
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm">WebM format</a>
    </p>
    <button id="chapterChange" value="Go To Next" onclick ="changeTheChapter();"/>

</body>
```

Comment: just looked up flow player, but yeah if IE6 is a requirement you should probably mention that. Oh and yeah that was just a hint. Quick example, Not looking to build the control for you.